# Distributed Java App on Docker swarm

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am new to docker and I am trying to run a distributed JAVA application over docker swarm.
I tested it on one node using the command docker-compose up and it works fine.

When I tried to deploy it as a service with the command

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file myfile.yml myapp
```

the component "im" is not able to connect with the component "orchestrator"

I use the label "orchestrator" as IP address for the component (it works with the simple compose up)

Any help?  below my compose file

I have created a compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
   zk:
      image: xxx/cep
      deploy:
         mode: replicated
         replicas: 1
      entrypoint: /ext-sw/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/zkServer.sh
      command: start-foreground
      ports:
       - 2181:2181
      networks:
       - cepnet
   orchestrator:
      image: xxx/cep
      deploy:
         mode: replicated
         replicas: 1
      entrypoint: /bin/runOrchestrator
      ports:
       - 9000:9000
      depends_on:
       - zk
      networks:
       - cepnet
   im:
      image: xxx/cep
      deploy:
         mode: replicated
         replicas: 1
      entrypoint: /bin/runIM -IP im -PORT 9901 -ID im1 -LOGID im1
      ports:
       - 9901:9901
      depends_on:
       - orchestrator
      networks:
       - cepnet
networks:
    cepnet:
enter code here
```

EDIT:
As said in comments my original problem was due to the IP assigned by docker to a container.

Below the output of the ping command run with the service name and hostname

```
root@90cfe6fc88ed:~# ping orchestrator
PING orchestrator (10.0.0.9) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.9: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.9: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.034 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.9: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms
^C
--- orchestrator ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2010ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.032/0.033/0.034/0.000 ms
root@90cfe6fc88ed:~# ping $(hostname)
PING 90cfe6fc88ed (10.0.0.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 90cfe6fc88ed (10.0.0.10): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.055 ms
64 bytes from 90cfe6fc88ed (10.0.0.10): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms
64 bytes from 90cfe6fc88ed (10.0.0.10): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.014 ms
^C
--- 90cfe6fc88ed ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2033ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.014/0.029/0.055/0.018 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) `depends_on` is not supported on swarm. Your application needs to be able to handle a situation where one service you depend on is not runninng (e.g try to reconnect until it becomes available)

If you want to test if this is really the issue wait for all services to run and then docker kill your service that had issues connecting. If it then runs fine its clearly a problem of it expecting the other service to already run.

Comment: the "swarm cluster" is up and running. At the beginning it was composed by three nodes now I removed two nodes just for testing on a single node

Comment: Sorry before your update I didn't see that orchestrator is a service. Please check my edited answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem seems to be the port. When I start the app with compose up, I am able to run from the im machine the command:     "telnet im 9000".  When I start it with the stack deploy I am not able to connect with telnet

Comment: you don't need to publish ports when using an docker (overlay) networks in order for one service to connect to the other

Comment: It seems that the problem is with the IP address. My JAVA app running in the container "orchestrator" bind itself on the port 10.0.0.2 while looking at ifconfig output inside the container it has the ip 10.0.0.3   This is quite strange to me becuase I use the container name the bind the socket in my JAVA app.  
Does docker assign multiple addresses (at least a pair) to a container even if I set only 1 network (the default overlay one)?

Comment: I don't understand your question. 10.0.0.2 is not a port?
If you want to communicate between services use networks and one service can contact the other service by using http:/${otherServiceName}:${otherServiceInternalPort}. You don't need published ports, you don't need to care about ips nothing.
Just make sure that you services don't have dependencies on each other (you're hinting at that with depends_on) because swarm ignores depends_on.
Thats all the help I can give you

Comment: Oh and I forgot: listen on 0.0.0.0:port on your application. That way you listen to any interface

Comment: port was a typo... 10.0.0.2 was the IP.
Finally I solved the problem...  Apparently docker uses an IP for the service name and an IP for each replica of the service. So If you have only one replica it would have 2 IPs... Starting a service on 0.0.0.0 could be a solution. If your application needs to access a particular replica you need to use the particular hostname of the replica to access it (that is the ID of the replica).